# Is it best practice to have a model for each form in Yii framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I am new to Yii (using Yii2) and I have seen that there are models such as **ContactForm** and **SignupForm**. I wonder if you think that it is best practice in MVC to have such models because it either has application logic such as the **signup()** and than it should belong to the controller. On the other hand it has a relation to the view because **FORM** is a view element. But I do not see how it is belong to the model. Maybe their functionality belong to a Service or ViewHelper?

I have been working with MVC for some time but it confuses me. Correct me if I am wrong and write your opinion.

Comment: I never used their pre-set "Form" models. It just comes down to a matter of preference.
NOTE: You're also asking for opinions on here, so you're question will be locked soon.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC models are designed to handle the modeling of information regardless of their representation. In many cases you can identify a number of information groups that together have a coherent meaning and shape situation properly, without which these data should be (as they are) directly stored in a database. In this case use is made of what is called in Yii2 Form Model. That is a model not directly connected to a database table that manages a number of attributes attributing them to a class and being able to manage all programming patterns applicants in MVC.
Granted this is not a good practice to have a model for each form. sometimes when the models and forms are few, this can happen. But it is necessary to have as many models as there are classes of information to be managed. Often the form of display are many more classes of data organization that is the model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the issue is still not clear to me. I will have to research more